# EvaluateJavaScript debug javascript function

Tags: javascript, swift, mobile-safari

I am using `WKWebView` to load an html page and use evaluateJavaScript execute a javascript function.

Here is what how I do it.

1. Load the html page with bunch of reference to javascripts and CSS files.

   `let request = URLRequest(url: "myhtmlpage.html")
   webView?.load(request)`

   myhtmlpage.html has script reference to myfunctions.js

   `<script src="js/myfunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
2. Inside myfunctions.js I have a function call `CalculateTax(amount)`
3. After loading the page at the myhtmlpage.html at the first step. I have a logic to pull necessary date to calculate "amount" after doing the calculation, I use 
   `webView?.evaluateJavaScript(CalculateTax('\(amount)');)` to execute a java script function to calculate tax and display tax on myhtmlpage.html.

I want to debug `CalculateTax(amount)` javascript function. I used safari developer tools and put break points at the place of `CalculateTax(amount)` but it is not getting to the break point. Any body knows how to debug a javascript function getting executed with `WKWebView`, evaluateJavaScript method.

Answer (score 1):

Use message handlers. You post them in your JS which will return values to Swift that you can print to the console in Xcode.

First, make sure you have a content controller and configuration set up:

```
var contentController = WKUserContentController()
var configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
```

Add yourself as the listener for your message name. Then assign the configuration to the content controller, and the controller to the web view:

```
contentController.add(self, name: "YOUR_MESSAGE_NAME")
configuration.userContentController = self.contentController
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: self.configuration)
```

Then implement the delegate method to listen for messages posted back from JS:

```
extension YourViewController : WKScriptMessageHandler {

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        if error != nil {
            if let str = message.body as? String { // or whatever you cast to
                print(str)
            }
        } else {
            // error handling
        }
    }
}
```

And post messages from JS like so:

```
// YOUR_MESSAGE_NAME needs to match what you registered for in the WKUserContentController
window.webkit.messageHandlers.YOUR_MESSAGE_NAME.postMessage(MESSAGE_CONTENTS);
```

Comment: Thanks Wes! This is a good work around if i have to evaluate certain values from the javascript execution. We are already using this callback to xcode from the javascript to get statistics for google analytics. I was looking for a way to do a line by line evaluation (F10 , step out) thing. However i was able to debug it using a hack. I used the command line execution to call the javascript function i wanted to test. copied the payload from the xcode and passed it to the javascript when i execute it. Sorry if i haven't explained it well.